How to implement web.DataReader correctly
I'm having a lot of issues pulling info using datareader. I get a huge error message and cant seem to find any answers. I've even tried the example from the site and still get errors.
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = web.DataReader('GE', 'yahoo', start='2019-09-10', end='2020-10-09')

This lengthy error occurs:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 df = web.DataReader('GE', 'yahoo', start='2019-09-10', end='2020-10-09')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:213, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    211         raise TypeError(msg)
    212     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 213 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py:379, in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    367     raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    369 if data_source == "yahoo":
    370     return YahooDailyReader(
    371         symbols=name,
    372         start=start,
    373         end=end,
    374         adjust_price=False,
    375         chunksize=25,
    376         retry_count=retry_count,
    377         pause=pause,
    378         session=session,
--> 379     ).read()
    381 elif data_source == "iex":
    382     return IEXDailyReader(
    383         symbols=name,
    384         start=start,
   (...)
    390         session=session,
    391     ).read()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py:253, in _DailyBaseReader.read(self)
    251 # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    252 if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253     df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    254 # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255 elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py:152, in YahooDailyReader._read_one_data(self, url, params)
    150 ptrn = r"root\.App\.main = (.*?);\n}\(this\)\);"
    151 try:
--> 152     j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
    153     data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154 except KeyError:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'


maybe there is no data for your parameters - so it gives None and code has problem. OR maybe yahoo blocked these data and now this module can't work - and maybe it will never work again (if yahoo will block data forever)

yfinance is the replacement for pandas-datareader and I would also suggest a smart cache so you aren't pounding on Yahoo too often.
See yfinance-cache at https://pypi.org/project/yfinance-cache/

It seems pandas_datareader module is not working as expected or may be some changes had happened in yahoo.
So in order to get the same formatted data you can use yfinance API:
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("AAPL", start='2019-09-10', end='2020-10-09')

Hope this helps

how to overcome the issue when the ssl certificate throws an error. I am running behind a firewall.
