how to use pandas-datareader to fecth stock information
I'm learning pandas and I'm trying to use pandas-datareader to fetch stock price to apply the correlation function, but I have searched online, using the code recommended with error
import pandas_datareader.data as web
df = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start='2024-01-01', end='2024-06-01')

I used jupyter 7.0.06
my datareader is lxml-5.2.2 pandas-datareader-0.10.0
my python version is 3.12
the result I got is as follow:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 df = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start='2024-01-01', end='2024-06-01')
File
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:213,
in deprecate_kwarg.._deprecate_kwarg..wrapper(*args,
**kwargs)
211         raise TypeError(msg)
212     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 213 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py:379,
in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause,
session, api_key)
367     raise NotImplementedError(msg)
369 if data_source == "yahoo":
370     return YahooDailyReader(
371         symbols=name,
372         start=start,
373         end=end,
374         adjust_price=False,
375         chunksize=25,
376         retry_count=retry_count,
377         pause=pause,
378         session=session,
--> 379     ).read()
381 elif data_source == "iex":
382     return IEXDailyReader(
383         symbols=name,
384         start=start,    (...)
390         session=session,
391     ).read()
File
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py:253,
in _DailyBaseReader.read(self)
251 # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
252 if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253     df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
254 # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
255 elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):
File
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py:152,
in YahooDailyReader._read_one_data(self, url, params)
150 ptrn = r"root.App.main = (.*?);\n}(this));"
151 try:
--> 152     j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
153     data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
154 except KeyError:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78343119/how-to-implement-web-datareader-correctly
